# Expression vectorial to magnetic field \$\vec{H}\$ in infinite semi-plane conductor

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-flux

I have some difficult to figure out the second expression about the contribution of magnetic field as you see below:

Problem:
A wire conductor, infinite long (Z axis), conduct a current constant equal to \$I_0\$ [A] to infinite semiplane, with condutivity uniform equal to \$\sigma\$[S/m]. Those variables \$r\$, \$\phi\$ e \$\theta\$ and the unit vectors \$\hat{r}_a\$, \$\hat{\phi}_a\$, \$\hat{\theta}_a\$ are the spherical system coordinates. The expression of A vectorial to magnetic field \$\vec{H}\$ in conductor region (A/m), (\$-\infty<x<\infty\$, \$-\infty<y<\infty\$ and \$z<0\$) is:

[image: image problem]

[image: alternatives]

**D is correct.**

My attempt:

I find the first expression kind easily:

Use expression to relate infinite wire and distance in fuction angle \$\theta\$ find:

$$H = \dfrac{I_0}{2\cdot \pi \cdot r\cdot \sin(\theta)}(-\hat{\phi}_a)$$
[image]

But the second expression which show the $$\cot(\theta) = \dfrac{\cos(\theta)}{\sin(\theta)}$$ I cannot to find to complete the answer D.

My answer would be

$$H = \dfrac{I_0}{2\cdot \pi\cdot r\cdot (\sin(\theta)+\cos(\theta))}(-\hat{\phi}_a)$$

Any tips?

Comment: What first expression do you mean?

Comment: @Andyaka notice the answer D: \$|\vec{H}| = \dfrac{I_0(1+\cos(\theta))}{2\pi r \sin\theta} = \dfrac{I_0}{2\pi r \sin\theta}+\dfrac{I_0\cdot \cos(\theta)}{2\pi r \sin\theta} = \dfrac{I_0}{2\pi r \sin\theta}+\dfrac{I_0\cdot \cot(\theta)}{2\pi r}\$. I find the first expression.

Comment: But you are not stating **what it is that you are trying to find**. Then you say you have found the first expression but, were you asked to find that expression? And, what does that expression relate to? Your question is not clear.

Comment: OK. I'll try to be a little clearer. I don't understand what the contribution of the magnetic field is with respect to the conducting semi-plane considering the spherical coordinate system. For me, if I consider the figure I drew and think that the half-plane also behaves like an infinite thread, but horizontally its contribution would be \$ \dfrac{I_0}{2\pi r \cos\theta}\$, which added to the first expression, would give \$ \dfrac{I_0}{2\pi r (\sin\theta+cos\theta)}\$.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not trying to find the answer through the expression, but rather trying to understand how this expression with \$ cot\theta\$ came about

Comment: Again, the first expression i find use the infinite wire analisys: \$ \vec{dl}=dr \hat{r_a} + r.d(\theta) \hat{\theta_a} + r.\sin(\theta)d(\phi) \hat{\phi_a}\$